# How to make subdomain on my localhost?

Tags: php, localhost

is it possible to  create subdomains on my localhost? like `sub.localhost`
and would like to know how subdomains work.

Comment: Check out the [HostAdmin](https://www.google.com/search?q=HostAdmin) extension.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Create a virtual host as such:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/public_html/sub"
</VirtualHost>
```

And in your hosts file add this line:

```
127.0.0.0       sub.localhost
```

[**Here**](http://digitalpbk.blogspot.ca/2007/01/making-subdomains-on-localhost.html) is a useful tutorial you might find helpful.

Comment: *.localhost should resolve out of the box, without adding anything to /etc/hosts :) Although in Debian I have this exact problem

Answer (score 11):

You can make your browser to point to any domain/subdomain that you want as long as you put the ip - hostname definition in your `c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file, for example:

> 127.0.0.1       localhost
>
> 127.0.0.1       sub.localhost

or on the same line separate by space:

> 127.0.0.1 sub.localhost subsub.localhost local.host

Answer (score 7):

Add the following to your local hosts file. On windows, it's located at `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`.

```
127.0.0.1       sub.localhost
```

Replace `127.0.0.1` with whatever IP address you want.