# Firefox not able to open subdomains

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, firefox, express

I have a nodejs app with express as backend which is running on `localhost`. I have subdomains associated with it like `user1.localhost`. These subdomains are opening in Chrome but Firefox throws `Server Not Found` error.

Does Firefox needs some configuration to allow subdomains?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18793883/how-to-make-subdomain-on-my-localhost

Comment: @Andrey : Thanks for the above link. But my question is what is the reason of disparity between Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the reason is that Chrome resolves *.localhost to localhost internally and other browsers request DNS server for subdomain.localhost (which obviously fails). You can use hosts files to make it work for them.

The reason Chrome does this is security reasons, you can read more about it [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=489973).